# Start a new line below not on the right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am appending two canvases below each line of text in a loop. But the next content keeps starting on the right of the second canvas of the previous record.

I want this

```
|text1                     |
|canvas1||canvas2|
|text2                     |
```

but instead I get

```
|text1                     |
|canvas1||canvas2||text2   |
```

This is what I have

https://jsfiddle.net/May_Y/2h6xz5c7/17/

```js
draw("canv_0");
draw("canv2_0");
draw("canv_1");
draw("canv2_1");

function draw(idname) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(idname);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // complete custom shape
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<div class="result-box" id="result-box">The result is : <br><strong id="result"></strong></div>
<p overflow="hidden">

  <text id="result0">------------------------This is my Text1--------------------------------</text><br>

  <canvas id="canv_0" width="250" height="250" color="red" style="position: relative; float: left; display: block; height: 200px; width: 200px;"></canvas><br>
  <canvas id="canv2_0" width="250" height="250" style="position: relative; float: left; display: block; height: 200px; width: 200px;"></canvas><br>

  <text id="result1">------------------------This is my Text2----------------------</text><br>

  <canvas id="canv_1" width="250" height="250" color="red" style="position: relative; float: left; display: block; height: 200px; width: 200px;"></canvas><br>
  <canvas id="canv2_1" width="250" height="250" style="position: relative; float: left; display: block; height: 200px; width: 200px;"></canvas><br>
</p>
```

How I can get the desired layout?

Comment: `text.append('<id="result'+idx+'">'` - what is that supposed to be …?

Comment: You are floating the canvasses, so clearing would have to happen on the next (block) element that comes after them.

Comment: And you are inserting this into a `strong` element that is child of a `p`, but what you are inserting contains `p` elements itself again - you can not nest `p` elements in HTML, that is not allowed. All in all, this is pretty chaotic what you are doing here …

Comment: @04FS Thanks for pointing it out. I did not notice that as it works fine in browser.  Updated the outer `<p>` to `<div>`.  Question updated

Comment: If you have each of those texts and their two canvasses wrapped in their own `p` element, then applying `overflow:hidden` to that should probably fix it. (And if it doesn’t, then please provide a proper [mre] first.)

Comment: @04FS Thanks. I tried with `overflow:hidden` but it does not work. Updated the question with jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply a `clear: both;` CSS property to the first block following a floated element, to prevent it to float. Here is an example with `<br style="clear: both;">`:

```js
draw("canv_0");
draw("canv2_0");
draw("canv_1");
draw("canv2_1");

function draw(idname) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(idname);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // complete custom shape
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<div class="result-box" id="result-box">
  The result is :
</div>
<p id="result0">
  ------------------------This is my Text1--------------------------------
</p>
<canvas id="canv_0" width="250" height="250" color="red" style="position: relative; float: left; display: block; height: 200px; width: 200px;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canv2_0" width="250" height="250" style="position: relative; float: left; display: block; height: 200px; width: 200px;"></canvas>
<br style="clear: both;">

<p id="result1">
  ------------------------This is my Text2----------------------
</p>

<canvas id="canv_1" width="250" height="250" color="red" style="position: relative; float: left; display: block; height: 200px; width: 200px;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canv2_1" width="250" height="250" style="position: relative; float: left; display: block; height: 200px; width: 200px;"></canvas>

<br style="clear: both;">
```